# jQuery Mobile: Unchecked Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've implemented jQuery Mobile, and I'm dynamically adding radio buttons. While the radio buttons are successfully added, I'd like to be able to see the faint circles to the left of the text when they are unchecked; when they are checked, the blue radio circle appears as it should, but there's nothing to be seen when they are not. This could just be the default behaviour, but all of the demos I've seen online suggest otherwise. To illustrate my problem, I've attached a screenshot.[image: Radio Button Issue]

After dynamically appending my radio buttons to my control group element, I call a function intended to apply jQuery mobile styling to the newly added elements.

```
function Add() {
var $newLabel = $('<label for="' + ID + '">' + text + '</label>');
var $newControl = $('<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-' + parentID + '" id="' + response.ID + '">');
$newLabel.appendTo("#ControlGroup");
$newControl.appendTo("#ControlGroup");
RefreshUI();
}

function RefreshUI()
{ 
     $("#ControlGroup").enhanceWithin()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: assuming you are using the latest version of JQM you don't need to trigger create. If i'm not mistaken that's an old method. Just use append and enhance within to refresh  the styles for your radio buttons. demo https://jsfiddle.net/ma7f55dc/ -- if that doesnt help the off state of the radio buttons have an opacity of (0.3) so check to see if the opacity is not set to (0). this is the css markup -- (.ui-checkbox-off:after, .ui-btn.ui-radio-off:after {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=30);
  opacity: .3;
})

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to resolve my issue (It isn't being set to 0, and I added the CSS). I'm adding the code I'm using to generate radio buttons to my question.

Comment: Yeah but you can see its invisible. Right click on it and inspect the element  to show you the CSS. You can do this on chrome or firefox